# Пропадает Fragment в ViewPager после анимации

Tags: java, android

Есть FrameLayout в котором с помощью

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.go_prev_in, R.anim.go_prev_out);
ft.replace(R.id.nm_frame, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

меняются фрагменты.

В одном из фрагментов есть ViewPager с табами.

```
mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

mViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager_new_messages);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.getCurrentItem();

        // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
        tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) v.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setViewPager(mViewPager);
```

У которого есть свой адаптр

```
public class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public ProblemFragment pf;
        public InfoFragment inf;

        public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    pf = new ProblemFragment();
                    return pf;
                default:
                    inf = new InfoFragment();
                    return inf;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            String title = "";
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    title = "Проблемы";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    title = "Информации";
                    break;
            }
            return title;
        }
    }
```

Но, когда я ухожу с этого фрагмента на другой, то у меня во время анимации пропадает контент внутри ViewPager.

Comment: Если анимацию убрать то все нормально?

Comment: Без анимации тупо не видно этого пропадания. Т.е. в начале анимации, пропадает контент внутри ViewPager